# How can I transform a map into *bytes.Buffer

Tags: go

I have the following Go code:

```
 1:   func SendHTTPPostRequest(url string, buffer *bytes.Buffer) bool {
 2:       // Do Stuff
 3:   }
 4:   
 6:   data := map[string]string{
 7:       "a": "b",
 8:       "c": "d",
 9:   }
10:   body, err := json.Marshal(data)
11:   statusCode, bodyBytes, err := SendHTTPPostRequest("http://localhost:11000/myEndpoint", body)
```

I get the following compile error in line #11: `cannot use body (type []byte) as type *bytes.Buffer in argument to SendHTTPPostRequest`.

What am I doing wrong?
How can I transform `data` so that it's correct type for SendHTTPPostRequest()?

Comment: Create a buffer and pass it: `bytes.NewBuffer(body)`

Comment: This is a very unhelpful comment.

Comment: Try reading the docs.

Comment: Note that the first response I gave is the answer to your question. It was written as a comment instead of an answer because your question could be completely avoided if you took the time to look at the docs. The error even tells you where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import "bytes"

...

body, err := json.Marshal(data)
body := bytes.NewBuffer(body)
```